# Android Studio Layout Editor strange green Markup

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout-editor

As shown in the Picture, my Layout Editor shows annoying green Markups between XML-Elements. Cant find a way to disable it.

Any ideas?

[image: Layout Editor]

Edit:
Strangely it seems to happen only when using FrameLayout

Comment: You have a FrameLayout inside a FrameLayout, why? You can move `@+id/container` to the outer one and achieve the same features

Comment: I deleted some parts of the layout for the sake of this example...

Comment: *Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view* -- from docs. Maybe Android Studio is trying to tell you this?

Comment: You might be right with that. I use them quite often for stacking Layouts. Maybe RelativeLayout suits better for this.

Comment: If you also apply `layout_weight`, it is fine. I think most people are moving towards CoordinatorLayout and ConstraintLayout nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you could try to go to Settings/Editor/Colors, then Fonts/Language Defaults, lastly Markup Tag and uncheck Background.

Comment: Have you installed any plug-in? Changed a preference or anything?